# « Loustic » au féminin ?

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire, synonymes

Il est un mot qui décrit bien certains individus, en particulier leur comportement, c'est le nom masculin « loustic ». Il se trouve que la langue française l'a « inventé » pour son besoin de caractériser des hommes (plutôt jeunes) et non pas des jeunes filles ou des femmes.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/loustic)) **B.** − P. ext. Individu facétieux. Synon. farceur, joyeux drille, plaisantin.
> Bande de loustics, faire le loustic.
>
> - Suivaient (...) ces messieurs de la Sorbonne en robes jaunes. «Tiens, les cocus...» s'écria en les voyant, un loustic (Morand,1900,1931, p. 15).V. *éditer* ex. de Ambrière
> - ... cette faille transversale ou ravine était devenue un lieu de rendez-vous pour tous les ivrognes du secteur, un repaire de joyeux loustics, un tripot, une cave où les soiffeurs se rendaient directement... Cendrars, *Homme foudr.*,1945, p. 17.

Le terme « loustique », que le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/loustique) ne semble pas avoir jugé bon de retenir, ne signifie apparemment [pas autre chose que « loustic »](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Les_helv%C3%A9tismes_de_Suisse_romande_au_XI/R_IcAQAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22loustique%22&dq=%22loustique%22&printsec=frontcover). Ce n'est donc pas le féminin, et apparemment il n'y en aurait pas.

Il y a bien le terme « *plaisantine* », que je ne connaissais pas tellement il est rare, mais je ne considère pas « plaisantin » comme un bon synonyme de « loustic », et si je trouve naturelle et utile une  extension de « loustic » qui s'appliquerait au genre féminin, je ne vois pourtant pas un terme satisfaisant.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/plaisantine)) Plaisantine, subst. et adj. fém.,rare.

La question a de ce fait deux parties.

- Le terme « loustic » pourrait-il être utilisé en parlant d'une personne du genre féminin ? (« une loustic », « la loustic » n'existent pas (Google Books).)
- Si une telle extension épicène ne peut vraiment pas être faite au français, quel serait un terme qui corresponde de près à « loustic » et qui pourrait être employé en parlant d'une personne féminine ?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145795/discussion-on-question-by-lph--loustic--au-feminin); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ce n'est pas parce qu'un mot est absent des dictionnaires qu'on doit s'interdire de l'utiliser.

> Dans la chambre 11, les rires fusent. Flore, pour ne pas changer, fait le pitre. Elle dériderait un régiment de « mornes-bilieux-grognons-hypocondres ».
>     Une infirmière entre, furieuse.
>     — Hé ! **la loustique**, ce n’est pas un peu fini, ce cirque ? Les malades dorment !
>     **La loustique** s’arrête net mais n’arrive pas à stopper l’alarme du jeu électronique qu’elle a déclenchée. Ça hurle. Heureusement, Cédric est plus habile.
>
> [Claire Mazard](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claire_Mazard), *Le redoublant*, 1992, Nathan

> Bienvenue sur le forum, eh ben tu tombes super bien, tu as une sacrée bande de loustics ( meme **une loustique** )
>
> yves31, [Corvettepassion](https://www.corvettepassion.com/t24752-nouveau-membre-pour-ballades-dans-le-vaucluse)

> elle doit avoir bien chaud **la loustique** ^^
> d'ailleurs je suppose que tu vas l'emmener voir le film la semaine prochaine non?!
>
> Hazelnut, [casadolcecasa.canalblog.com](http://casadolcecasa.canalblog.com/archives/2010/11/18/16251763.html)

> Enfin, connaissant **la loustique**, on ne peut jamais etre certain!!!
>
> Switcher, [forumremede.com](http://forums.remede.org/montpellier+%3A+facult%E9+de+pharmacie/sujet_42401_2.html)

> Ta note est pleine d'humour et d'émotion.  ça m'a l'air d'être **une sacrée loustique** ta fille!! Comme sa mère, je suppose?
>
> Miss Julie, [nipette.com](https://www.nipette.com/article-paroles-37832824.html)

Comment: Donc, cette variante de « loustic » qui ne s'est pas implantée pourrait devenir le féminin de « loustic » selon vous ; il répondrait à un besoin dans la langue.

Comment: Ce n'est pas que loustique "pourrait devenir" le féminin de loustic, loustique **est** déjà aussi le féminin de loustic. On le rencontre ailleurs que dans l'ouvrage cité, dans des forums, blogs ou sur Twitter par exemple. Il répond donc à un besoin. On retrouve un peu la même chose avec ***lascar*** et son féminin "officieux" ***lascarde***.

Comment: Plus généralement, j'aime beaucoup l'idée qu'en tant qu'auteur, on a le droit de prendre certaines libertés avec la langue, quoi qu'en dise l'Académie. C'est peut-être même une sorte de _devoir_ pour un auteur, pour faire vivre et évoluer la langue. Il y aura toujours une tension entre ce qui est perçu comme _correct_ à une époque donnée, et les mots dont un auteur a vraiment besoin.

Comment: @Frank Oui, une langue n'a pas de vie propre. Ce sont ses locuteurs qui l'enrichissent et l'appauvrissent au fil du temps. Les dictionnaires ont forcément un train de retard par rapport à l'usage. D'ailleurs, le français n'a pas "inventé" loustic, il l'a emprunté à l'allemand en substantivant l'adjectif *lustig* (amusant, joyeux).

Comment: Dans le texte cité en exemple, "loustique" apparaît d'abord dans la bouche d'un personnage, puis est repris par le narrateur. La première occurence pourrait être un usage volontairement abusif associé au caractère ou au franc-parler du personnage. Dans, le paragraphe suivant, il pourrait s'agir d'une liberté de style de l'auteur reprenant les propos précédents. *Cette analyse n'est qu'une hypothèse non vérifiée et peut-être totalement opposée à l'intention de l'auteur*.

Comment: @Graffito J'ai ajouté quelques références où l'intention des auteurs est incontestable.